# Use keycloak.protect() with express.Router()

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I want to secure my routes using Keycloak which is an open source identity and access management.
I have tried to follow their documentation but I was not able to make it work.

Here is my app.js file:

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const routePlaces = require( './routes/placesRoutes' );

const Keycloak = require( 'keycloak-connect' );
const session = require( 'express-session' );
const memoryStrore = new session.MemoryStore();

let kcConfig = {
    clientId =      'parking-app',
    bearerOnly:     true,
    serverUrl:      'localhost:8080/auth',
    realm:          'FlexParking',
    reamlPublicKey: 'MIIBIjANBg…'
}

var keycloak = new KeyCloak( {store: memoryStore}, kcConfig );

app.use( keycloak.middleware({
    //  here I think I have to place my routes
}));

app.use( '/places, routePlaces );
module.exports = app;
```

The server is created in a `server.js` file and all the endpoints are working perfectly before trying to use Keycloak.

Here is my `routePlaces.js` file:

```
'use strict';
const express = require( 'express' );
const place = require( '../controllers/placesController' );

router.route( '/gps' ).get( place.get_place_by_gps );
router.route( '/street' ).get( place.get_place_by_street );

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my `placesController.js`:

```
'use strict';

exports.get_place_by_gps = ( req, res, next ) => {
    res.send( ' GET places by the GPS position' );
}

exports.get_place_by_street = ( req, res, next ) => {
    res.send( ' GET places by the street name' );
}
```

I want my route ('/places/gps') to be protected using `keycloak.connect('...')` and the route '/places/street' to be used without any protection. How to configure the Keycloak middleware to do that?

```
app.use( keycloak.middleware({
    //  here i think i have to place my routes
}));
```

How can the route be protected like this:

```js
router.route( '/gps' ).get( place.get_place_by_gps, keycloak.connect('user'));
```

Comment: how do you access every secured (by keycloak) endpoint, is it accessed with a header containing "Authorization: Bearer + ${JWT}"? For example: " curl -X GET localhost/gps -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJucnZ1ZS1tcTJ3a09DaEtXUldaa1lWTko3OUpma1VxTTR0ZUFocVZIMzBJIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJhMTc2NjU5YS1iY2JkLf....' "

Answer (score 5):

```
> app.use(keycloak.middleware({
> 
> //  here i think i have to place my routes
> 
> }));
```

It is incorrect. You have to pass the `options` there.

```
    app.use(keycloak.middleware({
        logout: logoutUrl,
        admin: '/'
    }));
```

> How has to be my route that i want to protect:
>
> router.route('/gps').get(place.get_place_by_gps,keycloak.connect('user');
>   something as above?

```
keycloak.middleware()
```

Doesn't do any protection itself. It just tries to get `grant` data from the request and put it in the special object `request.kauth.grant`.
Also it does some additional things, like check for logout request.

To protect a resource you need to add `keycloak.protect()`

```
 app.get('/gps', keycloak.protect(), handler);
```

To not protect a resource just don't add anything

```
 app.get('/street', handler);
```

This is a more complex example from [keycloak-nodejs-example](https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example),
it uses a custom middleware

```
middleware(logoutUrl) {
        // Return the Keycloak middleware.
        //
        // Specifies that the user-accessible application URL to
        // logout should be mounted at /logout
        //
        // Specifies that Keycloak console callbacks should target the
        // root URL.  Various permutations, such as /k_logout will ultimately
        // be appended to the admin URL.
        let result = this.keyCloak.middleware({
            logout: logoutUrl,
            admin: '/'
        });
        result.push(this.createSecurityMiddleware());
        return result;
    }


    createSecurityMiddleware() {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            if (this.permissions.isNotProtectedUrl(req)) {
                return next();
            }

            const permission = this.permissions.findPermission(req);
            if (!permission) {
                console.log('Can not find a permission for: %s %s', req.method, req.originalUrl);
                return this.keyCloak.accessDenied(req, res);
            }

            this.protectAndCheckPermission(req, res, next, permission.resource, permission.scope);
        };
    }


app.use(keyCloak.middleware('/logout'));
```

Sources

https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/lib/keyCloakService.js#L69

https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/app.js#L60

Also you can refer for a more complex protection schema, using (resource, scope) in the [keycloak-nodejs-example](https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example)

Comment: Thanks so much, You gave me a lot of usefull information with awesome examples. I was almost giving up and starting implementing a normal authentication with webtokens.

Comment: @v.ladynev, with regards to every secured (by keycloak) endpoint, it has to be accessed with a header containing "Authorization: Bearer + ${JWT}" right? Example: " curl -X GET http://localhost/gps -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJucnZ1ZS1tcTJ3a09DaEtXUldaa1lWTko3OUpma1VxTTR0ZUFocVZIMzBJIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJhMTc2NjU5YS1iY2JkLf....' "

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul Keycloak doesn't protect endpoints from the question. They are protected by `keycloak-connect` library.