# Keycloak nodeJS always get 403

Tags: node.js, json, keycloak

I have a NodeJS application running which id like to protect with keycloak.

I've done everything like in other applications which are protected with KeyCloak (Roles, Scopes) and it just does not want to work.

My config.json :

```
{
 "realm": "<Realm>",
 "bearer-only": true,
 "auth-server-url": "https://<URL>/auth",
 "ssl-required": "external",
 "resource": "<serviceName>",
 "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
 "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Then i set it up like this:

```
let memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
let keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });
```

and then on a route:

```
keycloak.protect('')
```

i also added this at the beginning:

```
app.use(keycloak.middleware({
    logout: '/logout',
    admin: '/'
}));
```

The bearer Token which is generated is doublechecked with JWT.IO which states that it is correct..

Any help?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to answer this question for people who are stuck at the same point:

keycloak.protect(""); was the problem, as it searched for an role called "", but obviously it couldn't find one. Therefore it gave me an 403.

If you want the user to be authenticated, but he is not required to have any roles use keycloak.protect() with no argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Keycloak middleware

```
app.use(keycloak.middleware({
        logout: '/logout',
        admin: '/'
    }));
```

To protect a resource you need to add `keycloak.protect()` to the route

```
app.get('/gps', keycloak.protect(), handler);
```

To not protect a resource just don't add anything

```
app.get('/street', handler);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705242/3405171

Comment: No it doesnt work

Comment: @JureBeton You can find a working example here https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example

Comment: No, it doesnt work. When I send requests from postman to protect() route with client token it works fine, but when i do it fro mangular app i get forbidden 403