# Keycloak in Nodejs always returning 403 Access Denied Error

Tags: node.js, keycloak, bearer-token

Keycloak returns 403 Error when I send it token from my react frontend.

I have implemented the keycloak server and authentication in React. I can get the keycloak.token after a successful login and redirect in react.

I have followed tutorials I found and my setup is pretty much the same as this answer: [Keycloak nodeJS always get 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774891/keycloak-nodejs-always-get-403)

Unfortunately, I still get 403 - Access Denied - Error. I have setup a realm and below is my keycloak.json file and my code.

```
{
  "realm": "Weal V3",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "node",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

My code

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');


const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan('combined'))

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'some secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: memoryStore
}));

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
    store: memoryStore
});


app.use(keycloak.middleware());


app.get('/public', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'public' })
})

app.get('/secure', keycloak.protect(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
    res.json({ message: 'secured' })
})


app.get('/admin', keycloak.protect(), (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'secret' })
})


app.listen(5500, () => console.log('Server started on port 5500'))
```

I expect that when I navigate to http://localhost:5500/secure with Authorization: Bearer + keycloak.token from the react application I should get `{ message: 'secured' }`, but all I get is 403 Access Denied

Comment: Show the token. It might be invalid audience parameter, it should match app one `node`.

Comment: Thanks @vadim. I have been able to resolve it. It was the node version I was using that caused the error.

Comment: @EveristusOlumese what node version you were using and what's the version you switched to

Comment: @EveristusOlumese what was the node version you used?

Comment: what node version you were using? and what are the required version?

Comment: Joining the choir here, what was the node version before and which node version worked? (Meanwhile, I suspect pilot error on my part as I work through the same symptoms.)